# How do I get the networkId of an object?

Tags: unity

My clients have a way of spawning "defense" barriers and I would like to limit the number of defense barriers per client to 1; A way of doing this is to destroy the old defense (if any) and then spawn the new one. Since this defenses are spawned by the server, how can I tell the server to destroy only the defense that was created by that client?

I guess that by storing the networkID of the spawned defense I can later tell the server to destroy it and repeat. Am I attacking this right?

Having this:

```
[Command]
void CmdDefenseSpawned(string _playerID, string PlaceToDefenseName, Vector3 toDefense, Quaternion defenseRotation)
{
    Debug.Log("Player " + _playerID + " placed a defense on " + PlaceToDefenseName + " Position= " + toDefense);
    GameObject defenseInstance = Instantiate(defense, toDefense, defenseRotation);        
    NetworkServer.Spawn(defenseInstance);        
}
```

I would like something like this:

```
NetworkInstanceId defenseInstanceNetId = defenseInstance.NetworkIdentity.netID
```

So I can later delete the object whenever the client wants to spawn it again.

Comment: Why not just associate each barrier with a client? E.g. using a Map<Client, Barrier> - then you can just put the new barrier and despawn the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer:

```
   using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.Networking;

 public class Example : NetworkBehaviour
 {
     void NetworkDestroy(GameObject Object)
     {
         //Get the NetworkIdentity assigned to the object
         NetworkIdentity id = Object.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>();
         // Check if we successfully got the NetworkIdentity Component from our object, if not we return(essentially do nothing).
         if (id == null) return;
         // First check if the objects NetworkIdentity can be transferred, or if it is server only.
         if (id.localPlayerAuthority == true) {
             // Do we already own this NetworkIdentity? If so, don't do anything.
             if (id.hasAuthority == false)  {
                 // If we do not already have authority over the NetworkIdentity, assign authority.
                 // Keep in mind, using connectionToClient to get this NetworkIdentity is only valid for Network Player Objects.
                 if (id.AssignClientAuthority(connectionToClient) == true)
                 {
                     // If takeover was successful, we can now destroy our GameObject.
                     Network.Destroy(Object);
                 }
             }  else {
                 // Do nothing because we already have ownership of this NetworkIdentity.
             }
         } else {
             //Server only, so we can't do anything.
         }
     }
 }
```